# How to convert blob to image using jquery ajax?

Tags: php, jquery, blob

I have written a php script which retrieves a blob corresponding to an image from remote db. Now I want to grab that blob using jquery ajax call and then convert it to an image and set that image in a div.

I am curious to know, which is the best way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways of doing this. You could transform the blob into a BASE64 string and set the src attribute of the img tag to that BASE64 string.

It would however be easier to create a php page that serves that image directly. When the JS code needs the image it creates an img tag and sets the src attribute of that tag to the URL of the PHP page that serves images. Which image to serve can be defined by the URL Query string

Comment: Now the obvious question is, how you convert blob to image in php? Also, for that you may need to write a file for that particular image, isn't it? can you provide some pseudocode?